# Combine two Action Result MVC Scaffold

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new on MVC. How can I combine two action result on my below code:

```
public ActionResult TreeView()
    {
        var db = new PCNMSContext();
        return View(db.AssetRegisters.Where(x => !x.ParentAssetID.HasValue).ToList());
    }

public ActionResult AssetRegisterIndex(string SearchString)
    {
        var assetregisters = from m in db.AssetRegisters
                             select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            assetregisters = assetregisters.Where(s => s.AssetNumber.Contains(SearchString));
        }

        return View(assetregisters);
    }
```

The ActionResult above is .. 1st, to generate the list on the `TreeView` and 2nd is to generate the list on `Table` with `Search` Function.

My Model:

```
public class AssetRegister
{
     public int AssetID {get;set;}
     public string AssetNumber {get;set}
     public string AssetDescription {get;set;}
     public int? ParentAssetID {get;set;}

     [ForeignKey("ParentAssetID")]
     public virtual AssetRegister Parent {get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<AssetRegister> Childs {get;set;}
}
```

My View:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4">
           <div id="jstree">
               @(Html.TreeView(Model)
                     .EmptyContent("root")
                     .Children(m => m.Childs)
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "tree" })
                     .ChildrenHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "subItem" })
                     .ItemText(m => m.AssetNumber)
                     .ItemTemplate(
                          @<text>
                              <a href="@item.AssetID" desc="@item.AssetID">@item.AssetNumber</a>
                           </text>)
                    )
           </div>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="col-lg-1">
           @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
           <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Search">View</button>
        </div>
        }

        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <table> I didnt copy all, but this table contains a column of 'AssetRegister' model. There are 4 columns. AssetID,ParentID, AssetNumber,AssetDescription
</table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My script for jsTree:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var selectedData;
        $('#jstree').jstree({
            "core": {
                "multiple": true,
                "check_callback": true,
                'themes': {
                    "responsive": true,
                    'variant': 'small',
                    'stripes': false,
                    'dots': true
                }
            },
            "types": {
                "default": {
                    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-record"
                },
                "root": {
                    "icon": "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["dnd", "state", "types", "sort"]
        }).on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
            var i, j, r = [];
            for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
            }
            $('#SearchString').val(r.join(', '));
    });
</script>
```

So when I click the node, the text of the node will appear on `@Html.TextBox`.
The problem is, to load the data on table and to load the data on treeview is different.
1. How can I combine those ActionResult?
2. When text from node received by the textbox, The submit button should not be clicked, but it should be click automatically. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this all for the same page?

Comment: yes, on the same View...

Comment: And how are you wanting to call the `AssetRegisterIndex()` method - its has a paramater so is that parameter based on something in your `TreeView` view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, correct... So the text on the treeview would be a search parameter on the 2nd actionresult.

Comment: The use `@Html.Action(..)` in the `TreeView` view to display the initial results if you want all `AssetRegister` initially. And to filter the results basd on the textbox, you would need ajax to call the `AssetRegisterIndex` method and update the page (but that method need to return a `Partialview`, not a `View`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, renderpartial isn't it?

Comment: You could use `RenderPartial`, but that means your passing the model in the `TreeView.cshtml` to the `AssetRegisterIndex.cshtml` partial. In your case that may well be the case, but I'm not sure - the `TreeView()` method filters the result by `.Where(x => !x.ParentAssetID.HasValue)` and the `AssetRegisterIndex()` method does not

Comment: Just add more detail on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not having a ViewModel containing those you want to return in View?

```
return View(new MyModel{List1 = list1,List2 = list2});
```

Comment: I didn't get you. But, It's on the same model and the result is on the same view.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this type of requirement is using ajax to populate the data and then for filtering purpose.

You are submitting the form for searching purpose which is not a good practice.

Check my solution if it could help you.

**Step I:**

Change your Action Method and **Return JsonResult instead of ViewResult**:

```
public ActionResult AssetRegisterIndex(string SearchString)
{
  var assetregisters = from m in db.AssetRegisters
                             select m;

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
           assetregisters = assetregisters.Where(s => s.AssetNumber.Contains(SearchString));
    }

   return Json(assetregisters,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Step II:**

i. Remove @html.BeginForm

ii. Change type of button to 'button'.

iii.Create html for table.

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <button class="btn" type="button" value="Search" id="btnsearch">View</button>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="jstree">
            @(Html.TreeView(Model)
                     .EmptyContent("root")
                     .Children(m => m.Childs)
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "tree" })
                     .ChildrenHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "subItem" })
                     .ItemText(m => m.AssetNumber)
                     .ItemTemplate(
            @<text>
                <a href="@item.AssetID" desc="@item.AssetID">@item.AssetNumber</a>
            </text>)
            )
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-1">
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <button class="btn" type="button" value="Search" id="btnsearch">View</button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-7">
    <table class="tbl table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Step III:**

And finally ajax call.

Load the table with all data while the page is loading for the first time and then on button click load against the search text.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Loading Entire table on page loading
        LoadTable("");

        // on search
        $('#btnsearch').click(function () {
            var searchData = $('#SearchString').val();
            if(!searchData){
              alert("please enter your text");
              return;
            }
            LoadTable(searchData);
        });

        function LoadTable(searchString) {

            var table = $("table tbody");
            var tBody = "";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ControllerName/AssetRegisterIndex",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { SearchString: searchString },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
                        tBody = tBody + "<tr><td>" + elem.Col1PropertyName + "</td><td>" + elem.Col2PropertyName + "</td><td>" + elem.Col3PropertyName + "</td></tr>";
                    });

                    table.html(tBody);
                }
            })
        };
    });
</script>
```

Hope it will help you !!

Comment: Do NOT remove the `BeginForm()`. Do NOT change the button. You handle the forms `.submit()` event and cancel it, then make the ajax call so that client side validation etc is triggered.

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'PCNMS.Models.AssetRegister'

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am struggling for 2 days to find out the solution. Can you help me?